# Render page when database contents changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

So suppose I have a page that displays all the user's posts. Right now when the user creates a post, it stores it into the database. But that new post will not appear unless I log out of the app and log back in. How can I make it so that the post will appear without having to logout?

```
const [Posts,setPosts] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
const fetchUserPosts = async () => {
const res = await client.get('/fetch-user-posts')
setPosts(res.data.posts)
}
fetchUserPosts()
},[])
```

And in the rendering I just took the `Posts` and map it to display its contents. I know this problem exists somewhere but I don't know what keywords to google. I have seen posts asking to use JQuery but I bet there is a simpler solution?  Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the function of fetchUserPosts out of the useEffect like this:

```
    const fetchUserPosts = async () => {
        const res = await client.get('/fetch-user-posts')
        setPosts(res.data.posts)
    }
```

Now, useEffect will be like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUserPosts()
    }, [])
```

Next, wherever you function of create user posts is, call fetchUserPosts() like this:

```
    const addUserPosts = async () => {
        // logic of adding new user post
        if (success) {
            await fetchUserPosts()
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you it works, I wonder what is this design pattern called? I am certain its not in the tutorial from React

Comment: @kdh13 Basically by taking the function out of useEffect it allows itself to be available outside. Now, we need the updated list of posts whether be it adding new post, editing post or deleting post so we can call the GET request after success operation in either of above and the component will re-render with the updated data :)