# React Calling function from another file and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

Hello I am trying to render the updated stuff from the database whenever the update is invoked to the database. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401810/render-page-when-database-contents-changes) but right now my "add" method is not in the same file as the "fetch" method like in the linked question. I tried the below but it still isn't working:

file 1: (the return method will render the `UploadedImages` by mapping them)

```
const [UploadedImages,setUploadedImages] = useState([])

const fetchUserAllPhotos = async () => {
    const res = await client.get('/get-photos')
        setUploadedImages(res.data.photoList)
    } 

useEffect(()=>{
        
    fetchUserAllPhotos()
},[])
```

file 2:

```
import {fetchUserAllPhotos} from './Gallery/AllPhotos';
const addNewPhoto = async () => {
        if (success) {
            await fetchUserAllPhotos()
        }
}
```

However inside the file 1's return (render) method it is not giving the updated result whenever a new photos is added (I need to sign out and sign back in in order to see the change). How can I go about solving it?

what if the function is wrapped inside another one?

```
export default function PhotoGrid(props){
    const [UploadedImages,setUploadedImages] = useState([])
    
    const fetchUserAllPhotos = async () => {
        const res = await client.get('/get-photos')
            setUploadedImages(res.data.photoList)
        } 
    
    useEffect(()=>{
            
        fetchUserAllPhotos()
    },[])

}
```

Comment: You have a separation of concerns problem here in that `fetchUserAllPhotos` is a utility function for calling your API to retrieve some data which should probably be defined separately in it's own file. You can then import that function in any components that need to make that API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add this line at the bottom of file1

```
export {fetchUserAllPhotos}
```

In general, every time you want to import function, array, object etc it should look like this:

file1:

```
const func = () => {
  //implementaion of the function
}

export {func}
```

file2:

```
import {func} from './file1' //you need to give the path of file1


func() //now you can use the fanction everywhere in file2
```

note: you can export as many functions as you wants just be careful it important to use the same name in the export and in the import

```
export {func1, func2, func3, obj1, abj2, arr1, arr2}
```

if you are exporting function from react component you need to define the function outside the component

```
const func = () => {

}

export default function MyReactComponent(prop) {
//implementation of your component
}

export {func}
```

If you need to use prop of your component inside the function you can pass this prop as a function parameter.

I recomend to avoid from exporting function from react component because when your project becomes bigger it will start to be frustrate to find were you impliment each fanction. instead it is a best practice to add a new js file that you implement there all the fetches function, I usually call this file api.js
This file should look something like this (I took this code from my project there I used axios to make the fetches to the server):

```
import axios from "axios"

const url = 'http://localhost:8080'

const api = {
getQuestions : async () => {
   return axios.get(`${url}/question/all`)
 },
getQuestionById : async (id) => {
   return axios.get(`${url}/question/${id}`)
 }
}

export default api;
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if the ```fetchUserAllPhotos``` is wrapped inside another function? (I edited the question). How can I call it in this case? Doing ```import {PhotoGrid} from './file1'``` and calling ```fetchUserAllPhotos()``` in file 2 does not work anymore.

Comment: I edit my post, I hope this answers your question